# Table aware parsing of a string field

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have a table of videos with a field, filename, and some of these videos are split in multiple parts with the starting frame number of the video part appended to the end of the filename separated by a '_'.

I want to get the integer which represents the starting frame for each filename, so for e.g.:

```
movie.avi : frame=0
movie_500.avi: frame=500
```

For the two files above, I can get it with a regular expression on my table:

```
SELECT coalesce(substring(filename FROM '_(\d{2,7}).avi$')::int, 0) FROM table;
```

However, how to deal with the case when the filename of the video might include numbers at the end. Say I have the two files:

```
anothermovie_100.avi: frame = 100 (WRONG!)
anothermovie_100_500.avi: frame = 500
```

My select statement above will give me the wrong frame starting number. I want to know from looking at my table that anothermovie_100 has frame=0 because there exists another filename in the same table which contains anothermovie_100 and finishes in three digits at the end.

So basically for a table with the four above-mentioned rows, I would like my select statement to give me this:

```
movie.avi: frame=0
movie_500.avi: frame=500
anothermovie_100.avi: frame=0
anothermovie_100_500.avi: frame=500
```

So the query has to somehow know if the filename string is not contained entirely in another filename string of the same table, in which case it must return frame 0 and not the last digits on the filename converted to integer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is modeling the data - you should keep a reference to which movie each file belongs to.

Otherwise, your data may be ambiguous. Assume you have the files `movie.avi` and `movie_500_500.avi`. How would you tell (regardless on SQL syntax, just in plain English) whether `movie_500.avi` is in fact the 500 frame of `movie.avi` or the 0 frame of `movie_500_500.avi` ?

Comment: Yes I thought about that, unfortunately this is for a task where the filenames have already been generated and I have to parse the folder cotaining them. The case you mention above could indeed happen, in which case I would like that movie_500 is part 0 of a series containing itself and movie_500_500, and movie.avi is a standalone clip (its 'parent' is itself a 'child')

Comment: But let's exclude this more complex case. What i'm more interested is having an sql statement that considers whether or not 'filename' for a given row is a substring of 'filename' of any other row of the same table (which would be the case where I always return 0 for frame number).